# Elastic Search Query to get results for multiple keywords(i.e Country name)

Tags: elasticsearch

Key String will be like

"india,singapore" without quotes.

How to split and search the keyword

Expected result will be match the country with india or singapore.

So far i tried..

```
{
  "_source": "country_name",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
             "country_name.keyword": "india,singapore"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
     }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

But it will showing only those content have match the exact key string "india,singapore"

Answer (score 1):

you can use **terms** query in place of **term** query like below:

```
{
  "_source": "country_name",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
             "country_name.keyword": ["india","singapore"]
          }
        }
      ]
     }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```